# I can't delete a file because it seems 'open'

Tags: java, multithreading, wav

I'm coding something with an audio part with WAV Files and after 2 days of searching for a bug, I really don't know where the problem is. I guess my thread doesn't stop and that prevents me from deleting a file, but when I'm debugging everything goes well and I've no exceptions or errors.

Here is my interface:

[Picture of my interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbarv.png)

So when I want to delete a file by clicking on *delete button* that launches '**DeleteTrack**' method and it works, but when I listen to it first thanks to *listen button* that launches '**PlaySound**' method, I can't delete it, it's like if nothing happen.

Also, when I use '**PlaySound**' and then I try to delete my file from windows I have this:

[Windows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHhNT.png)

Thank you for reading and I'll be very grateful if you could help me and sorry if my English isn't perfect.

> **GatherFiles** method just return my list of waves I've verified it's not null
>
> **MajListAudio** method refresh my list if I add or delete a song

```
public void DeleteTrack() {
        String song_name = audioList.getSelectedValue();
        File[] listeOfFiles = GatherFiles(null);
        // Loop to find the file to delete and then delete it.
        for(int i=0;i<listeOfFiles.length;i++){
            if(song_name.equals(listeOfFiles[i].getName())){
                listeOfFiles[i].delete();
            }
        }

        // Refresh the list
        MajListAudio();
    } 
}
```

> So here is the function when I guess there is a problem.

```
 public void PlaySound(File sound){


        thread = new Thread(){
            @Override public void run(){

                try {

                    // Initialize a clip with our sound file

                    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
                    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(audioStream);

                    // Variable that will updated to fix the percentage of the progressBar
                    int progressContains =0;

                    // Size in Seconds of our music
                    int sizeAudio = (int) (clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000000);


                   clip.start();




                   do{

                       // indice allow us to know how much the progress bar has to grow every second. We divide with 100 because it's the maximum
                       //of the bar
                       int indice = 100/sizeAudio;

                       // Refresh the value of the bar and prepare her next value
                        progressBar.setValue(progressContains);
                        progressContains+= indice;

                        // The main thread is sleeping for 1s
                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                    }while(clip.isActive());

                   //Reset the bar after a play
                    clip.stop();
                    clip.close();
                    audioStream.close();




                   progressBar.setValue(0);





                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
                }  catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        thread.start();

}
```

> Others functions

```
public File[] GatherFiles(DefaultListModel myModel){

        // If you want to get the list without implementing the model
        if(myModel == null){

            File[] both = Concatenate(getListOfFiles("\\cryptedAudio"), getListOfFiles("\\audio"));

            return both;

        // Same with a model
        }else{
            audioList.setModel(myModel);

            File[] both = Concatenate(getListOfFiles("\\cryptedAudio"), getListOfFiles("\\audio"));

            return both;
        }
    }

public File[] getListOfFiles(String endPath){

            String folderPath = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
            folderPath= folderPath.substring(0, folderPath.length()-1);

            File folder = new File(folderPath+endPath);
            File[] listeOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            return listeOfFiles;
    }


    /*
     *Return a new Array that contains borh arrays in parameters
     */
    public <T> T[] Concatenate (T[] a, T[] b) {
        int aLen = a.length;
        int bLen = b.length;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] c = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), aLen+bLen);
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);

        return c;
    }
```

Comment: So when your code execute `listeOfFiles[i].delete();` an exception is thrown?

Comment: I suggest to add at your post the source code of `GatherFiles` method.

Comment: No there is no exception, alright I add my other function.

Comment: You can also try using [Files.delete](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) that way if delete fails you get an exception.

Comment: Are you sure you leave the do/while loop?

Comment: @matt Hi, so I used Files.delete and in the error log it written that "The process cannot reach the file because this file is used by another process."

Comment: There are some rules that we should consider mandatory, and closing resources that you open is one of them. This is an old article, but still worth a read: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03216/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really suspect your threading is an issue. You wait one second after the sound finishes, at the very least. So maybe your delete happens too soon. One way around this, is to read everything from the file, and then make the sound. That way the file should always be closed.

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(sound.toPath());
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                                      new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes) 
                               );
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioStream);
```

Since your problem appears to be your file not getting released to the system, we use `File.readAllbytes` which reads the whole file, and release it back to the OS before you even play a sound.

The concept behind your original setup *should* work, but it appears that your loop does not finish before you try and delete the file. It could also be that you start more than one thread to access the file.

Comment: You were right, it works now ! Thank you very much, but could you explain a little bit more ? I'm not sure that I understand why it didn't work, due to 1s at the end ?

Comment: I mean that I waited for 1 hour and I couldn't delete the file aswell so if it's a 1s problem I don't get it

Comment: I am not sure why the File does not get released back to the system. `Files.readAllBytes` will let go of it after reading the file. Maybe you are starting your loop more than once. Or maybe you are not exiting your loop. Just firing off a thread like that can create some challenges, it might be good to use an executor service.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

```
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioStream);
// play the audio...
clip.close();
audioStream.close();
```

This is just making sure that the `AudioInputStream` is getting closed properly since I'm not sure that `clip.close()` is closing it (though one would think it should...)

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't work even it was an other mistake from me ! but the error log says : "The process cannot reach the file because this file is used by another process."

Comment: Ah, sounds like perhaps a previous execution of your program is still running in the background. You'll just have to kill the process and that should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

This method API  `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound)`  returns an  `AudioInputStream` that you should close.

So better if you first assign the returned value to a local variable:

```
AudioInputStream inputAudioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
```

And then you can open it using the `clip` instance:

```
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(inputAudioStream);
```

Finally don't forget to close the `inputAudioStream` variable:

```
clip.close();
inputAudioStream.close();
```

I strongly suggest to use [the try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try(AudioInputStream inputAudioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound)) {
   // Initialize a clip with our sound file
   Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
   clip.open(inputAudioStream);

    [.... ] your code

    clip.close();
    progressBar.setValue(0);
} 
[.... ] your catch code
```

Comment: Ho okay I didn't know for this, but I made it with the code under from 'dumtruckman' and it's still the same

Comment: So I used a try catch on the delete action and I have the following error : " The process cannot reach the file because this file is used by another process."

Comment: So do you have an exception now? if yes, you have to understand what's the "other" process that is using file.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `GatherFiles` open the same file twice. Try to check that.

Comment: Hmm I don't think, I checked and when I open my app and delete a file without listening to it before it works, so If it works I guess that this function doesn't affect anything no ?